# Can I run a cron job after every 65 mintues. Getting failed to parse error

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to run a cron job every 65 minutes. Getting the following error while uploading the app on GAE.

An internal error occurred during: "Deploying aws-spending to Google".
schedule every 65 minutes synchronized failed to parse.

If this is not possible is there a way to run a cron job after another one finishes?

**My cron.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<cronentries> 
    <cron> 
        <url>/metricsposter</url> 
        <description>Servlet that posts billing metrics to Graphite</description>
        <schedule>every 65 minutes synchronized</schedule> 
    </cron> 
</cronentries>
```

Comment: Here is how my cron.xml looks

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
  <cron>
    <url>/metricsposter</url>
    <description>Servlet that posts billing metrics to Graphite</description>
    <schedule>every 65 minutes synchronized</schedule>
  </cron>
</cronentries>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an error on GAE part. Just tested it - you can set 60, 80 or 90 minutes, but not 65, 70,75 or 85 minutes.

You should file an error.

Answer (score 2):

It couldn't parse your cron.yaml

you probably forgot the : after schedule.

Hint: show your code if you want people to be able to help you.  No one's going to go through the effort to hack your machine to debug your problem.