# Google app engine cron.xml failed to parse

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I have the following cron.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
  <cron>
    <url>/_ah/admin/cronjob?job=aaa</url>
    <description>aaa cronjob</description>
    <schedule>every 60 minutes</schedule>
  </cron>
  <cron>
    <url>/_ah/admin/cronjob?job=bbb</url>
    <description>bbb cronjob</description>
    <schedule>every 250 hours</schedule>
  </cron>
 </cronentries>
```

When deploying to google app engine, it says

> com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: schedule every 250 hours failed to parse

it works with 24 and 96 hours, but not 200, 240, and 192. Is there an upper limit not written in docs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717281/can-i-run-a-cron-job-after-every-65-mintues-getting-failed-to-parse-error may be related

Comment: An issue has been opened : https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8786

Comment: I imagined that was something similar. It would be interesting to know if there is some sort of reletionship that you can use to guess a legal time nearby your needs...